# Is It Possible To Change Camera Interpolation?

Tags: animation

In Animation, my DEFAULT INTERPOLATION is BEZIER

I wanted to do a camera movement wherein it starts with BEZIER INTERPOLATION first then it changes to LINEAR then back to BEZIER INTERPOLATION? Just like those action movie shots where it start from slow to fast to slowmow then back to fast.

I tried doing it but I failed or just doesn't know how it works. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a new interpolation per Key. The interpolation will then be effective until a new key sets a new interpolation.

Not an expert animator but I would stay with bezier and use the different handle types for this instead. It's less confusing and gives full control.

Comment: i'm not sure what you're talking about but sure is interesting. will look to it. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

With the camera selected (and animated) click on the Properties Editor icon, then choose Graph Editor. When you're in that editor, select the keys whose handles you want to change and press V, then V again if you want Vector tangents (= linear)  (I'm using Blender 2.79.)

[image]

Comment: let me try that :)